# How do I exclude certain clicks from stopPropagation() ? Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div #basket which is shown using the JQuery slideDown function.

To slide the div back up the use can click anywhere on the page.

```
$(document).click(function () {
  $("#basket:visible").stop(true, true).slideUp("slow");
});
```

Of course I don't want the div to be closed when a user clicks inside of it. So I use:

```
$("#basket").click(function (e) {

   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Now the problem I'm having is that a form is contained in the div and this cancels ALL click functions within the div.

Is there a way to close this div by clicking on the page without cancelling all clicks?

Comment: What are your form event handlers that this is stopping?

Comment: Are you sure that your form is inside this div and not outside? `e.stopPropagation()` stops only propagation of events up the DOM tree, so if you have a node inside #basket it should still catch the event.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `event.target`: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

This will allow you to check which element the event is firing on within the click handler and act accordingly.

Comment: This is pretty ambiguous, not really a clear solution since the `.target` will be any child element...this only gets you 1/3rd of the way to the check you need to perform.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean now. Well, in that case I'll be interested to see a solution for the other 2/3.